# How to get the enum type from a string in vb.net

Tags: string, vb.net, enums

I have declared a enum as below:

```
Public Enum Myenum
    val1 = 0
    val2 = 1
End Enum
```

Now I have a variable with the name

```
Dim str As String = "Myenum"
```

How can I use variable str to access the values of the enum?

Comment: I not sure exactly what you're asking.  Maybe you could provide some context?

Comment: I have declared the enum as said in the question. Now I have received a string value programmatically in my program, say str with value "Myenum" and this value is the name of the enum I have declared. Now I want to use str dynamically to access the values of the enumtype Myenum. Is it possible?

Comment: By context, really I'm ask what are you planning on doing with it.  Passing an enum name around as a string seems odd, so trying to understand a little bit more about your situation so can give the best advice

Comment: It could be as simple as if str = "Myenum" Then....

Comment: I am working with a database where many tables are there, now after running a query I have received a name as "Myenum" which is the name of a table also. Now I want to use this variable of type string to access the values of previously declared enumtype.

Comment: Public Function GetTableName(ByVal name as String, ByVal val As Integer) As String
        'How to use this name to get the values of enum type 
    End Function

Comment: Well based of that info, I don't even understand what the purpose of the enum is.  Can you not just query the db to get the required value when you need it rather using the enum.  Perhaps you need to update your question with the full detail and expected results

Comment: It sounds like you are asking how to solve a problem that you have created yourself by bad application and/or database design. I suggest that you address the design issue rather than implementing a solution that simply compounds the issue.

Comment: How are you going to use the table names?  What is the underlying problem that you're trying to solve?  This feels like it's an XY problem.

Comment: Suppose I have 5 tables and 5 enum type for each table is declared, now when I am looping through, I get the name "Table1" as string. I want to use this String value to get access to the values of enum type Table1 programmatically.Tried to use [Enum].GetName(GetType(Table1), val), but it says invalid use of string, enum type exepected. So how can I convert the String "Table1" to an enum type?

Answer (score 1):

If the scope where the Enumerator is defined is a class object, you can use the current instance type to get a member corresponding to the Enumerator type name, using [GetType().GetMember()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmember):

If the Enumerator(s) may not be public, specify [BindingFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags) that allow to include non-public members. Add `BindingFlags.IgnoreCase` if needed.

```
Imports System.Reflection

Dim enumTypeName = "MyEnum"

Dim flags = BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or 
            BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.IgnoreCase

Dim myEnumTypeInfo = Me.GetType().GetMember(enumTypeName, flags).FirstOrDefault()
If myEnumTypeInfo IsNot Nothing AndAlso Type.GetType(myEnumTypeInfo.ToString()).IsEnum Then
    Dim myEnumValues = Type.GetType(myEnumTypeInfo.ToString()).GetEnumValues()
    '[...]
End If
```

If the enumerator type is defined in a wider scope, you can use [Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly) and get the type from [DefinedTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.definedtypes):

```
Dim myEnumType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().
                 DefinedTypes.FirstOrDefault(Function(t) t.Name = enumTypeName)

If myEnumType IsNot Nothing AndAlso myEnumType.IsEnum Then
    Dim myEnumValues = myEnumType.GetEnumValues()
    '[...]
End If
```